# Is $\frac{\sigma(n)}{{2n}}$ submultiplicative or supermultiplicative?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum, multiplicative-function

This question is an offshoot of this [earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3643139).

It is known that the *abundancy index*
$$I(n) = \frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$$
is a [multiplicative function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function).  (Note that the *divisor sum* $\sigma$ is also multiplicative.)

How about
$$J(n) = \frac{\sigma(n)}{2n}?$$

**MY ATTEMPT**

Suppose that $\gcd(x,y)=1$.  Then
$$J(xy) = \frac{\sigma(xy)}{2xy} = \frac{\sigma(x)\sigma(y)}{2xy} \neq \frac{\sigma(x)}{2x}\cdot\frac{\sigma(y)}{2y}.$$

In general, we have
$$2J(x)J(y) = \frac{\sigma(x)\sigma(y)}{2xy} = J(xy).$$

This implies that
$$J(xy) = 2J(x)J(y) > J(x)J(y),$$
for all $x,y$ such that $\gcd(x,y)=1$.  This means that
$$J(n) = \frac{\sigma(n)}{2n}$$
is supermultiplicative.

**QUESTION**

> Is my understanding of the notion of a *supermultiplicative* function correct?

Comment: It is correct. And generally, by the same argument, if $\mu(x)$ is multiplicative then $a\mu(x)$ is supermultiplicative when $0<a<1$, and submultiplicative when $a>1$.

Comment: Thank you for confirming, @Conifold!  Please write your last comment out as an actual answer so that I can upvote and accept it.  =)

Comment: I honestly do not understand why this was downvoted.  Any form of feedback, hopefully constructive, would go a long way towards improving future questions/posts.  As it is, I am totally clueless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument is correct and can be generalized. Suppose $\mu(x)$ is any non-negative multiplicative function and $0\leq a\leq1$. Then we have $a\geq a^2$, and therefore
$$a\mu(xy)\geq a^2\mu(xy)=a^2\mu(x)\mu(y)=a\mu(x)\,a\mu(y).$$
In other words, $J(x)=a\mu(x)$ is supermultiplicative. By analogous argument, it is submultiplicative when $a\geq1$.